# Connecting two functions in R

Tags: r, function

**Question:**

Suppose I have a function called `Hy` (**see R code below**). If I want to have the 3 objects in the `Hy` function become input for the `By` function what should I do?

**Note:** These functions should not become a closure function (i.e., combining `Hy` and `By` into a single function), instead the `Hy` and `By` functions must remain "**separate**."

**Details:**

```
Hy <- function(n){

  A <- rnorm(n)
  B <- rcauchy(n)

invisible( list(A = A, B = B, n = n) ) ## Making all elements & arguments recognizeable 
                                        # outside the function "Hy".

}

Hy(2)
```

Now the `By` function needs "A", "B", and "n" from the `Hy` function to work:

```
By <- function(A, B, n){

  C = A + 1 
  D = B + 1
  E = n + 1

 return( list (C = C, D = D, E = E) )
 }

By(A = A, B = B, n = n)  ## HERE I need A, B, n from "Hy" function above to be recognized and used 
                          # as input for "By" function
```

Comment: You pass the variables to the function. Since `Hy` nicely returns the variables in a list, you can use `do.call` to call `By` using the arguments in the list `args`: `do.call(what = By, args = Hy(n))`

Comment: @Gregor, I'm fairly new to R, could you please provide a fuller response (and I'll accept and upvote).

Comment: One rather silly option: change `return` to `c` or `list` and then run `with(Hy(1), eval(body(By)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to assign the results of `Hy` and pass them to `By`:

```
hy_res = Hy(n)
by_res = By(A = hy_res$A, B = hy_res$B, n = hy_res$n)

# or use with() for a little less typing
by_res = with(hy_res, By(A, B, n))
```

Since the arguments are in a list, you can also use `do.call` which calls a function on a set of arguments provided in a `list`:

```
by_res = do.call(what = By, args = Hy(n))
```

Note that functions in R **cannot** return multiple arguments, so you should probably rewrite the last line of `By` to be `return(list(C, D, E))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update `A` and `B` as well in the global environment use `<<-` as assignment operator inside `Hy` function.

```
Hy <- function(n){

  A <- rnorm(n)
  B <- rcauchy(n)

  invisible( list(A = A, B = B, n = n) ) ## Making all elements & arguments recognizeable 
  # outside the function "Hy".
}

By <- function(A, B, n){

  C = A + 1 
  D = B + 1
  E = n + 1

  return( list( C , D, E ) )
}

Hy_vals <- Hy(1)
By(A = Hy_vals$A, B = Hy_vals$B, n = Hy_vals$n)
# C        D        E 
# 2.718926 1.586720 2.000000
```

Comment: OP just edited a "Note" in a way that seems to invalidate this approach...

Comment: Ok, looks fine to me. (I'm not your downvoter.) Another way: `with(Hy(1), By(A = A, B = B, n = n))`, besides the more natural `do.call` way. Oh, never mind, just saw Gregor posted those.

Comment: I had been the down-voter (sorry I didn't comment immediately!) because I don't like `<<-` and it seemed unneeded. Downvote removed now that `<<-` is gone. (Though I still don't like the recommendation in the first paragraph. Newbies especially should be encouraged to use standard functional programming without side effects.)